# Substitution box for AES

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

I need to implement AES (Advanced Encryption Standard). According to standard, in each round I substitute bytes using s-box (ex.: 4F -> 84). My question is do I need to store s-box in my c++ source code as variable or can I compute it for each byte?

Comment: Note that naive implementations of an s-box might be vulnerable to side channel attacks (for example timing).

Comment: what do you mean by naive implementation?

Comment: Is there really no implementation you can use?  Implementing your own crypto is generally not a good idea.  Especially if you haven't considered questions like CodeInChaos's.

Comment: i do not want to use it, i am just learning, so i wanted to implement for fun and practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind the S-Box is that it is revertible during decryption. As such the values in the S-box are constant. Computing the S-box for each byte is redundant and unnecessarily repetitive.

You should either copy and paste an [existing table](https://gist.github.com/mb720/6662deb7bfbff28d080e4302196d16c2) or compute it once in the beginning. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box) site has an explanation and some examples of initialization of the S-box.